# how to use mapOverLays with fragmentMap

Tags: android, android-layout, fragment

I am using `SupportMapFragment Map V2`

in my app but i am getting error on these lines please tell me their alternative or solution

```html
 List<Overlay> myOverlays = mMap.getMyLocation(); // here mMap is SupportMapFragment variable i.e GoogleMap mMap;
MyOverlay.projection = mMap.getProjection();
MyOverlay.projection (error area)
mMap.getController().setCenter(gpFirst);
mMap.getController() (error area)
```

and erorr is this on List myOverlays = mMap.getMyLocation();

```html
Error:(309, 48) error: incompatible types
required: List<Overlay>
found:    Location
```

now please help me to do this

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is pretty much clear,

Look at this, `List<Overlay> myOverlays`

Which is a list of Overlay and requires another list object. But you are using

`mMap.getMyLocation();`

which will return a location not a list.

Basically you are trying to assign a location into a list, which will definitely not work.